# Execute js code in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a piece of code that server sends to react component and this piece of code is set as a component property. This code includes a div tag and a script tag inside it. I need to execute and run this code in React component. Dangerously Set innerHTML doesn't work for me - js code isn't running in this case. Are there any variants to make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) for this.

But you need to be aware of the security implications it has. Especially you need to make sure you are using secure connections to your server and don't publish malicious code to your users.

Answer (score 0):

React does not recommends use innerHTML. But if you very need to, you can use

```js
function createMarkup() { return {__html: 'First &middot; Second'}; };
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />
```

More info https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html

Comment: I've tried it, but unsuccessfully. I need to insert such piece of code:
<div id="someId"><script>...some functions...</script></div>